# How to optimize such simple data (event) casting Class?

Tags: c++, events, casting, char

So I have created compilable prototype for a graph element that can cast its data to subscribed functions.

```
//You can compile it with no errors.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std ;

class GraphElementPrototype {

    // we should define prototype of functions that will be subscribers to our data
    typedef void FuncCharPtr ( char *) ;

public:
    //function for preparing class to work 
    void init()
    {
        sample = new char[5000];
    }
    // function for adding subscribers functions
    void add (FuncCharPtr* f)
    {
        FuncVec.push_back (f) ;
    } ;

    // function for data update
    void call()
    {
        // here would have been useful code for data update 
        //...
        castData(sample);
    } ;  

    //clean up init
    void clean()
    {
        delete[] sample;
        sample = 0;
    }

private:

    //private data object we use in "call" public class function
    char* sample;

    //Cast data to subscribers and clean up given pointer
    void castData(char * data){
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < FuncVec.size() ; i++){
            char * dataCopy = new char[strlen(data)];
            memcpy (dataCopy,data,strlen(data));
            FuncVec[i] (dataCopy) ;}
    }

    // vector to hold subscribed functions
    vector<FuncCharPtr*> FuncVec ;

} ;


static void f0 (char * i) {  cout << "f0" << endl; delete[] i; i=0; }
static void f1 (char * i) {  cout << "f1" << endl; delete[] i; i=0; }

int main() {
    GraphElementPrototype a ;
    a.init();
    a.add (f0) ;
    a.add (f1) ;
    for (int i = 0; i<50000; i++)
    {
        a.call() ;
    }
    a.clean();
    cin.get();
}
```

Is it possible to optimize my data casting system? And if yes how to do it?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to say that "this simple app eats 5% of my CPU." How long does it take to run? Have you profiled it to see what pieces of this are particularly expensive? Do you know where your performance hotspots are?  (For what it's worth, your code with its manual resource management looks quite unsafe.)

Comment: So you want to optimize this but you don't care about how much time it takes to run or how much it loads the CPU?  If you want to optimize this, **use a profiler** to find out what parts you should focus on.

Comment: My point is is it possible to make this class any better from C++ code writting professionals prespectives, and how to do it.

Comment: Why  manual resource management looks unsafe and how to avoid it in such case?

Comment: You should be using a smart pointer, like `auto_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr`.  You should never have to say `delete` in your code:  you should always use containers that manage resource lifetimes for you (like the aforementioned smart pointers) instead of trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Implement the program correctly and safely
- If performance Not Acceptable

  - While Not Acceptable

    - Profile
    - Optimize
- Done!

In my experience, premature optimization is the devil.

EDIT:

Apparently while I was formatting my answer, another James ninja'd me with a similar answer.  Well played.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to optimize my data casting system? And if yes how to do it?

If your program is not too slow then there is no need to perform optimizations.  If it is too slow, then generally, improving its performance should be done like so:

1. Profile your program
2. Identify the parts of your program that are the most expensive
3. Select from the parts found in step 2 those that are likely to be (relatively) easy to improve
4. Improve those parts of the code via refactoring, rewriting, or other techniques of your choosing

Repeat these steps until your program is no longer too slow.